# How to know the internet connectivity of an android device connected to pc via USB without using adb command?

Tags: java, android, networking, appium

Please tell me if there is a way to know the **internet connectivity of android device** connected to pc via USB **without using adb command**.
I'm running appium server to run tests and i need to check internet connection on my phone before performing tests in it.
is there any way?please help out

Answer (score 0):

enable USB tethering on your android device and try ping to any website and see the connectivity from your test scripts.

Comment: no i need to check whether my mobile is connected to internet not the pc tethering does'nt work i guess

Comment: Through usb tethering you are sharing the internet connectivity of your mobile device to pc. Hence, from your script you can do a ping. Ideally, ping goes via a your mobile device internet connectivity only.

Comment: can i ping from the connected usb tethering network is there any way like ip addr or something?? because i cant disable LAN i need to run scripts from server using GUI in client PCs in which mobiles are connected

Comment: no need to specify any ip address. it is just as usual way, write script to ping any website.

Comment: When you enable usb tethering, you are actually accessing the internet connectivity of your mobile device. Manually you can verify by opening browser. In your case you can use some script to see the connectivity. I hope you understood.

Comment: ya got to know but i need to ping any website with known source ip.for example my pc is connected to 2 networks after turning on tethering so how will i ping from a particular network??

Comment: i just checked by doing ifconfig on ubuntu, i could see there is a different interface and ip address mentioned there for each of the source of network. using this info i guess you can use ping -i and specify the source ip address.

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 1: Add in manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Step 2: Use belo method
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); 
            return !ipAddr.equals("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: how will you communicate to my connected phone.because the scripts are running in pc! not inside my mobile.

Comment: what is manifest and where will i find that?@Prabhav thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put beloved code in Manifest and java file it will return Boolean for Net is On/Off

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

     public static boolean isInternetOn(final Context context) {
            final boolean[] haveConnectedWifi = {false};
            final boolean[] haveConnectedMobile = {false};

            RxPermissions.getInstance(context)
                    .request(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
                    .subscribe(aBoolean -> {
                        if (aBoolean) {
                            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService
                                    (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
                            for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
                                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                                    if (ni.isConnected())
                                        haveConnectedWifi[0] = true;
                                if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                                    if (ni.isConnected())
                                        haveConnectedMobile[0] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });


            return haveConnectedWifi[0] || haveConnectedMobile[0];
        }
```

also add in gradle:

```
  compile 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.7.0@aar'
```

Comment: @AutoCodex2017 follow path: app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
Only permission add in Manifest
and if it will help you than pls upvote and accept ans